# How can I change a node's position without using actions in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have 2 classes (that are important here), a *Player* class and a *GameScene* class. I have a method in the *GameScene* class (*createSceneContents*), that is called by *didMoveToView*. in the *createSceneContents* class I call a method from the *Player* class called *newPlayer* which returns a SKSpriteNode with a size, color, and physics body.

In the *Player* class there's also a method called *movement* which returns what the new x position of the sprite should be:

*movement:*

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
@interface Player ()
@property CMMotionManager *motionManager;
@property CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData;
@end

-(float)movement {
  self.accelerometerData = self.motionManager.accelerometerData;
  float xAccelerationPosition = 0;
  if ((self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)<-0.2) {
      xAccelerationPosition = -2 * self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;

  }
  if ((self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)>0.2) {
      xAccelerationPosition = 2 * self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;

  }
  return xAccelerationPosition;
}
```

To change the player's position I want to set the players position equal to the return value of the movement method, but when I try to do this I get an error. How should I do this? Should I do it this way, or is there a better way?

Comment: Please describe the error you are seeing and also post the code where you use `movement`.

Comment: First I got a expression not assignable then I changed things and now I get a bad receiver type. I also don't know how to use the movement method. I can do this: [self setPlayer] but I can't access its position ([self setPlayer.position.x]?)

Comment: How have you tried to "set the players position equal to the return value of the movement method"?

Comment: I've been messing around by doing things like [self setPlayer] etc. I'm just desperately trying stuff here.

Comment: I've now figured something out: [self.player setPosition:CGPointMake([self.playerData movement], self.player.position.y)]; this gives me no errors

Comment: It does technically work, but it doesn't move the way I want. Still I'm wondering if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change player's position by simply set it's `position` property. And if the task is that simple, just keep using it.

But let's take a look if it needs to set the gravity force on player, or inertia.

In that case you need to use SpriteKit [Physics Simulation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html). At first, all the object you need to be under the simulation must have physics bodies. It's not a big deal to add a body to sprite node

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(player.size.width/2, player.size.height/2)];
// your player now have a body, you can set it's density or another properties
```

To change the body (and the node body attached with) position you can use impulses and forces.

```
[player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0,1)];  //up impulse
```

Your `movement` method perfect suits to task. Just use `acceleration` value as that impulse.

Answer (score 1):

Your movement method returns a `float` but the player's position is a `CGPoint`, you cannot sign a float to a `CGPoint` is what gives the error. You can set the player's position to a new `CGPoint` :
`self.position=CGPointMake(self.position.x+[self movement],self.position.y);`